# Out of order execution - no Ajax involved

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experiencing some out-of-order execution in javascript, and it's not related to any ajax calls or such. The main bulk of code is a possibly slow DOM manipulation, followed by a method call. In every single case, the function call is being fired before the DOM manipulation finishes.

Here is my code:

```
$(this).parents('dd').siblings('dd').each(function(){
  var filter_name = $(this).attr('data-filter-type');
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected', function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('date')) {
        $('form[name="filter-form"] input[name="from"]').remove();
        $('form[name="filter-form"] input[name="to"]').remove();
      } else {
        $('form[name="filter-form"] input[name="' + filter_name + '"]').remove();
      }
      console.log('removed');
    });
  }
});

var filter_type = $(this).parents('dd').attr('data-filter-type');
var filter_input = 'form[name="filter-form"] input[name="' + filter_type + '"]';
if ($(filter_input).length > 0) {
  $(filter_input).val(filter_value);
} else {
  $('form[name="filter-form"]').append('<input type="hidden" name="' + filter_type + '" value="true">');
}

doStuff($(this));
```

In my console, I am seeing the result of doStuff before I am seeing the debug.

Anybody have any ideas how to make the function call wait?

Comment: The browser is free to delay rendering as much as it desires. You can't force anything to appear on the screen. You can only ensure the browser knows how it _should_ look like.

Comment: I don't think you're using `removeClass` correctly. The function you're supplying should return a string of class names to be removed.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Apologies, this was also another attempt at making the browser wait until the DOM is updated before continuing. Wrapping things in anonymous functions seems to work in many cases. For the meantime, I guess it's safe to ignore that oversight on my part, as this part of the code still functions correctly (that said, I will remove this).

Comment: Well holy moly @AndrewWhitaker, I don't know what I did there but you just nailed it. Previously was executing out of order, so i did this - undid it, and it's now executing in order. Thanks kindly! (you should submit your answer, so I can +vote you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overload of `.removeClass` that takes a function, but it's not a callback function (that operation is completed synchronously). I'd recommend removing the function argument to `removeClass` and placing the code immediately after that call:

```
$(this).parents('dd').siblings('dd').each(function(){
    var filter_name = $(this).attr('data-filter-type');
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        if ($(this).hasClass('date')) {
            $('form[name="filter-form"] input[name="from"]').remove();
            $('form[name="filter-form"] input[name="to"]').remove();
        } else {
            $('form[name="filter-form"] input[name="' + filter_name + '"]').remove();
        }
        console.log('removed');
    }
});

var filter_type = $(this).parents('dd').attr('data-filter-type');
var filter_input = 'form[name="filter-form"] input[name="' + filter_type + '"]';

if ($(filter_input).length > 0) {
    $(filter_input).val(filter_value);
} else {
    $('form[name="filter-form"]').append('<input type="hidden" name="' + filter_type + '" value="true">');
}

doStuff($(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap all your DOM manipulation into a function accepting callback as a parameter:

```
var manipulateDOM = function(callback){
...
if(typeof callback === "function")callback();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
manipulateDOM(function(){
   doStuff(param);//I am not sure about the context so you need to figure out the value of param
})
```